# Rails autoload has_one relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have models Order and OrderItem. I'd like to autoload the Items once an order is loaded.
Something like this:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items, :include => true
end
```

or

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  include :order_items
  has_many: order_items
end
```

I'm sure that I have seen something like that but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: The first one is fine. The `include :order_items` is not valid

Answer (score 0):

You can use a default_scope like this:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items

  default_scope includes(:order_items)
end
```

`:include` in the `has_many :order_items` definition is used to eager load second-order associations, that is associations defined in `OrderItems`.